# A C/C++ library for FIR filter design with "Don't Care region"

Tags: filter-design, c

I need to get coefficients for my FIR filter. 
I know my pass band lets say between 350 - 400 Hz 
And my stop band(s) lets say 200 - 250 and 500 - 500 Hz, 
The other regions in the spectrum I simply don't care. I want the Filter to be relaxed in this regions so be more effective in pass and stop bands.

I am looking for a library with a  simple interface that I will just give passband and stop bands and number of taps. Than I will get my coefficients.

What I found is [aquila example](http://aquila-dsp.org/articles/updated-frequency-domain-filtering-example/), but I couldn't see how can I define relaxed regions.

Can you please advise me a C/C++ library with relaxed, pass, stop bands and easy to use even for a computer scientist?

Comment: Why don't you design the filter in one of the many available packages (Octave, SciPy, etc.) and use the resulting coefficients in your filter implementation?

Comment: I need information on run time I have a big application depending on this coeffecients.

Comment: So you need to continually re-design the filter in real-time and it's no option to store coeffs for different specs in tables?

Comment: Yes, I am doing microphone array simulation with speaker verification. I found the speaker on run time in the room that run in simulation via speaker verification. And I find the strong noises by their energy in the same radius. Their location can be changed according to the setup. I need to put nulls in to positions of noises and ones in to position of speaker rest regions can be relaxed. Coefficients will assign to my mic. array aparture weights.

Comment: Wouldn't you normally do this with an adaptive filter, not with a fixed filter that is changed all the time?

Comment: @MattL. Unfortunately I am not that experienced to say yes or no. But as I know adaptive filters controls the result of the filter and do some gradient tricks which seems a overkill for my case. This advise came from my thesis adviser and he also said there are many tools which I couldn't find. By the way thanks a lot for your patient responses to my uncertain question because of my lack of knowledge.

Comment: OK, what I don't understand yet is if you want to do spatial or frequency filtering. In your question you defined pass bands and stop bands in terms of frequency, but in one of your comments you said you need to place nulls in the direction of the noise, and ones in the direction of the desired speaker.

Comment: I need spatial filtering. What in the end of day I just need to calculate coefficients like a FIR filter given pass and stop bands ( angles in spatial domain) . Like T domain can be carried to Frequency domain with FFT. Sensivity (array weight coefficient) can be carried Angle Directivity domain. If I know angles that I want to null, I can find my coefficient with IFFT.  Because more people knows Frequency filtering I ask my question like I need frequency filtering

Comment: A long time ago I co-authored [a paper on that topic](http://publik.tuwien.ac.at/files/pub-et_3265.pdf). Have a look if it's useful. You basically just have to set up and solve a system of linear equations to get the weights.

Comment: I believe the frequency sampling method of filter design will let specify only the regions of the spectrum you care about. I don't know if you'll gain anything from it though.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85: Indeed, a frequency sampling method won't work, because it doesn't allow you to define "don't care" regions. The easiest way to solve the OP's problem is a least squares design.

Comment: Try Berchin's Frequency Domain Least Squares.  See: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=101953&searchWithin=%22Authors%22:.QT.Berchin,%20G..QT.&newsearch=true and http://www2.units.it/ramponi/teaching/DSP/materiale/Ex_5_2.m

Comment: @MattL. In the paper you mentioned you use capon's beamformer. But I have been instructed that I don't need a statistical beamformer and a simple IFFT will be enough. What I found similar in the internet is:  http://www.jpier.org/PIERC/pierc02/04.08031302.pdf. This is my 6th term in master thesis whatever do I couldn't make it work. Maybe my advisers directing me into wrong direction and I need to use Capon's beamformer as you do.

Comment: No, it's not Capon's beamformer, it just looks like it mathematically. It is in fact a deterministic beamformer based on estimated user and interference DOAs. We construct an artificial covariance matrix based on the DOAs, instead of actually estimating the covariance matrix. So it's a totally deterministic design, once the DOAs are fixed.

Comment: @MattL. I think I must understand the paper you sent. But to understand it I should understand Capons and Barletts beamformer. Your responses are more helpful than my thesis advisers thanks a lot.